# Charging Card Nonce Errors

Tags: php, square-connect

Having some issues with my card charging actions, just want to make sure this whole process is ok:

I've embedded the payment form on my web page (`https://mysite.mydomain.com`) and I can get the form to generate a nonce. I then pass that to my back end server on that sub-domain which forwards the request to another back end server I have on a different sub-domain (`https://mysite-2.mydomain.com`). This second back end server is the one that processes the card charge. They both are on the same domain but I'm getting a `CARD_DECLINED` error back from the charge endpoint. I'd just like to confirm if what I'm attempting to do is possible to rule that out of the possible causes for the error.

Both are connecting to the same application id (I tested this and when I changed application ids the error became `NOT_FOUND`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to charge from a different server than you generate the nonce from. In fact, since the charging is done from the the back-end, you don't really need a publicly accessible domain for the code that does the charging. Have you tried using the sandbox, does that work? Are you using a card that you use regularly?

Comment: Hi Tristan, thanks for the quick reply. I've managed to get it working with the sandbox with the sample cards so I think I'm on the right track!